# Fetch Json Data Set Using Parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to fetch JSON data set using UrlFetchApp but unfortunately am not able to do so. The reference code and data are attached, any help is highly appreciated.

CODE

```
function doGet(e) {
  var sheetId = "sheetid";
  var primaryEmail = e.parameter.primaryEmail;
  var softwareId = e.parameter.softwareId;
  var licensedScriptIds = e.parameter.licensedScriptIds;

  if (!primaryEmail || !softwareId || !licensedScriptIds) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("ERROR: primaryEmail, softwareId, and licensedScriptIds parameters are required.");
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data.shift();
  var primaryEmailIndex = headers.indexOf("primaryEmail");
  var softwareIdIndex = headers.indexOf("softwareId");
  var licensedScriptIdsIndex = headers.indexOf("licensedScriptIds");
  var jsonData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][primaryEmailIndex] == primaryEmail && data[i][softwareIdIndex] == softwareId && data[i][licensedScriptIdsIndex] == licensedScriptIds) {
        jsonData.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  if(jsonData.length === 0) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No match found");
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  }
};
```

JSON DATA

```
[{"Primary Email Address":"abc@gmail.com","Software ID":"TBBINV0719SS","Software Version":"Enterprise","License Status":"Expired","Start Date":"2019-07-26T18:30:00.000Z","Expiry Date":"2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z","License Type":"User","License(s)":1,"Licensed User(s)":"abc@gmail.com","Domain":"","License Key":"","Software Status":"","Licensed Script ID(s)":""},{"Primary Email Address":"ca@gmail.com","Software ID":"TBBINV0719SS","Software Version":"Enterprise","License Status":"Expired","Start Date":"2019-07-26T18:30:00.000Z","Expiry Date":"2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z","License Type":"User","License(s)":1,"Licensed User(s)":"ca@gmail.com","Domain":"","License Key":"","Software Status":"","Licensed Script ID(s)":""}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you told us what the error is or what doesn't work we could help.

Comment: With the help of above code I'm fetching the Google Sheet Data as JSON in WebApp out, now I want to to access the row data using WebApp url with parameters like primary email and software id and if parameters is not match returns error.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const d = '[{"Primary Email Address":"abc@gmail.com","Software ID":"TBBINV0719SS","Software Version":"Enterprise","License Status":"Expired","Start Date":"2019-07-26T18:30:00.000Z","Expiry Date":"2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z","License Type":"User","License(s)":1,"Licensed User(s)":"abc@gmail.com","Domain":"","License Key":"","Software Status":"","Licensed Script ID(s)":""},{"Primary Email Address":"ca@gmail.com","Software ID":"TBBINV0719SS","Software Version":"Enterprise","License Status":"Expired","Start Date":"2019-07-26T18:30:00.000Z","Expiry Date":"2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z","License Type":"User","License(s)":1,"Licensed User(s)":"ca@gmail.com","Domain":"","License Key":"","Software Status":"","Licensed Script ID(s)":""}]';
  let arr = JSON.parse(d);
  let hs = Object.keys(arr[0]);
  let o = arr.map(ob => hs.map(h => ob[h]));
  o.unshift(hs);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Sheet0:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Primary Email Address | Software ID | Software Version | License Status | Start Date | Expiry Date | License Type | License(s) | Licensed User(s) | Domain | License Key | Software Status | Licensed Script ID(s) |
| 2 | abc@gmail.com | TBBINV0719SS | Enterprise | Expired | 2019-07-26T18:30:00.000Z | 2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z | User | 1 | abc@gmail.com |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | ca@gmail.com | TBBINV0719SS | Enterprise | Expired | 2019-07-26T18:30:00.000Z | 2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z | User | 1 | ca@gmail.com |  |  |  |  |